# Visual C++ 2010 vector debug - no contents shown

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, debugging, visual-c++, stl

When I try to access a vector in the VC++ 2010 debugger, the only available elements are "_M_start", "_M_end", and "_M_end_of_storage". An example screenshot as follows:

[image: Vector debug issue example]

I remember a while back being able to access the actual contents of a vector, but for a long time this has not been the case (I've been able to live with it for a while). Is there a particular setting/feature that I've accidentally turned off or am I missing something completely?

Comment: are you using STLport or MS STL?

Comment: Either your installation of VC++ is screwed up or you are using a non VS2010 STL code that has not been recompiled for VS2010

Comment: First is it a debug build and do you have debug symbols? Second you can delete your solution *.sdf file to reset intellisense etc.

Comment: It may be because it's a `vector<CMeshEdge>` and VS doesn't know how to display a `CMeshEdge` object. Do you have the same problem with a `vector<int>`?

Comment: Yes it's a debug build, and no, unfortunately an int vector is the same. @NirMH - I should have mentioned that I'm using an SDK called Marmalade that enables cross-platform mobile development. Maybe I could be using STLport inadvertently? (A link here: [link](http://madewithmarmalade.com) ) Another thing: I just made a quick console app with a vector and I was able to access its contents in the debugger. This is indeed probably an issue specific to the SDK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is known that VS IDE can't display debug information of STL containers which are not Microsoft owned STL. i had the same issue while using STLPort library.

but, you can still use the watch to explore the vector's content, it would just be more tedious.
You can access the vector's elements by using an array indexing approach over the _M_start member. Add to your watch

```
meshEdges._M_start[0]
```

You'll then be able to see the content of first element of the vector.
There is no simple way to explore/view the entire vector's elements, you'll have to iterate it yourself, but it is still something.

You can read more in this link http://umairsaeed.com/2009/11/23/visualizing-stlport-data-structures-in-visual-studio-debugger . It describes how to add the above "knowledge" to the VS IDE Watch component. I'm not sure it is up to date to your VS2010 compiler, but you can explore yourself.

Comment: Thanks, I might look into a specific autoexp visualiser for the STL containers the SDK I'm using employs. Either way, like you mentioned there are other (albeit more tedious) methods to debug vectors.